# Class for synchronization of database access

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, qt, design-patterns

I have a singleton class for managing database access from multiple threads. The class has to meet the following requirements:

1. There can be simultaneous read operations, but writing has to be exclusive (no other writes or reads).
2. A single connection should be reused for multiple queries (within a thread).
3. Each thread needs to have it's own connection to the database.
4. The interface should not reveal implementation details and only expose access to resources (so the client is not aware whether it's working with a database, files or memory)

My current solution uses `QReadWriteLock` which takes care of synchronization, however all threads are using a single database connection, which is not safe. Below is a simplified version.

```
class ResourceManager
{
public:
    bool initialize(const QString& databasePath);
    bool shutdown();

    static ResourceManager& get()
    {
        static ResourceManager instance;
        return instance;
    }

    QByteArray getResource(int resourceId)
    {
        QReadLocker locker(m_lock);
        QSqlQuery query(m_db);
        // ...
    }

    bool setResource(int resourceId, QByteArray data)
    {
        QWriteLocker locker(m_lock);
        QSqlQuery query(m_db)
        // ...
    }

private:
    QSqlDatabase m_db;
    QReadWriteLock m_lock;
}
```

My idea is to implement some kind of connections cache, like the following:

```
QHash<ThreadHandle, QString> m_connectionCache; // thread handle - connection name

// then
if (!m_connectionCache[QThread::currentThread]) // Create new connection
QSqlQuery query(m_connectionCache[QThread::currentThread]);
```

The problem here is that I can't think of a good clean-up mechanism which would get rid of connections which are no longer needed, so the map will keep growing up with every new thread.

Does it seem like a good idea? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems to me like the required synchronization should be implemented in the DB, not the client. What happens when you have multiple instances of this app running?  The sync you are building here is ineffective.

Comment: The application is guaranteed to be single instance. Also I am limited by sqlite engine.

Comment: In your example you're caching `QString`s but not connections. If I don't mind `QSqlDatabase` is a connection, therefore you can cache them

Comment: @borisbn It's a Qt specific thing, the connections are accessible by it's name, which can also be passed as a parameter to `QSqlQuery` constructor. I may as well store the connection object or any other type of handle.

Comment: @jaho SQLite is compiled threadsafe by default. I seem you don't need to manage threads yourself.

Comment: Thread safety for sqlite means that you won't corrupt the database by accessing it from multiple threads, but you still need to manage synchronization and connections yourself.

Comment: @jaho Actually, SQLite has two modes of multi-threading support: `SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD` and `SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED`. In 'serialized' mode, which is the default, it's fully safe to share context structures (connections, statements etc.) between multiple threads. See http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_covering_index_scan.html#sqliteconfigserialized

Comment: @user4419802 OK, that could possibly work, however I'd somehow need to access sqlite C API from Qt to set SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED option. I'll try looking into that.

Comment: @jaho SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED is the default. And SQLite library itself is normally embedded into Qt driver. Though it's possible to revise the driver source code, ensure the defaults are set, and re-build the driver, but it would be no-op. Another (a bit paranoid) option is to build _static_ SQLite plugin, include sqlite3.h and invoke sqlite3_config() before QSqlDatabase::addDatabase().

Comment: @user4419802 Looking at qt database drivers I can't see this options set anywhere, so I'd assume they are the defaults, however I am getting errors from internals of QSqlQuery when running multi-threaded tests. It looks like it's a Qt restriction: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module

Comment: @jaho Yes, this option is not (usually) set by Qt, it is default in SQLite itself (sources are under 3rdparty/ directory tree). What's concerning Qt Sql module insafety, well, it seems that nothing could be done with this, except bypassing/rewriting it completely :(

Answer (score 0):

Connections are accesible by their names, **but** you pass `QString` to `QSqlQuery`'s constructor and this string is treated as SQL-query, but not connection name.

Fortunately `QSqlDatabase` contains the cache you need. It accessible to read by [QSqlDatabase::connectionNames](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#connectionNames) and to write by [QSqlDatabase::addDatabase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase)

Comment: How to reference a connection or where to store the cache are not really the problem. It's the connection lifetime. Whether I use my own cache or `QSqlDatabase` I will be adding new connections with each thread without ever deleting them.